# want to get diff of two timestamps in millisec in stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with this code:

```
select pick_id 
into pickid 
from prov_adapter_pmonitor 
where pick_id = 1;

select count(*) 
into no_of_picks 
from prov_adapter_pmonitor;

WHILE pickid < no_of_picks
loop
    SELECT pick_end_time
    INTO ts1
    FROM prov_adapter_pmonitor
    WHERE pick_id=pickid
    AND count  > 0;

    SELECT pick_start_time
    INTO ts2
    FROM prov_adapter_pmonitor
    WHERE pick_id=pickid+1;

    SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,ts2,ts1) from prov_adapter_pmonitor;
    select count into cnt from prov_adapter_pmonitor where pick_id=pickid;

    rslt := rslt+diff;
    cnt1 :=cnt1+cnt;

   pickid  :=pickid       +1;

end loop;
```

I want diff interms of millisec of my two timestamps ts1 and ts2 ,these timestamps are there in my entity, but it is giving exception at third select statement

Please give me any idea regarding this

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? And what's the error?

Comment: oracle 11g and that is procedure it compiles successfully but while running it is giving error timestampdiff select statement

Comment: *What error?* I think timestampdiff  is _not_ an Oracle-Function but mysql...

Comment: actually i want diff of two timestamps in milliseconds

Comment: Excuse...it is an Oracle Function ;) What ist the Error-Message/code? i.e. ORA-12345

Comment: then how to get diff of two timestamp variables

Comment: `timestampdiff` is a TimesTen function, not an Oracle RDBMS function (see [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/timesten.1122/e21634/oracle_tt.htm#TTCAC350)).

Comment: ok,,,but how to get the diff of the two timestamps in milliseconds for example ts2 and ts1 contains the two timestamps then i want total diff in milliseconds

Comment: Bit late, but possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22606161/266304).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing mysql and oracle syntax. I think what you need is EXTRACT

```
select extract(second from (ts2 - ts1)) as diff from dual;
```

Comment: Error(45,74): PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Oh, there wasn't any information about database when I answered. You can try with `from dual` for Oracle

Comment: it is giving only seconds but i want total seconds like hours,mins are also coverted into sec and added to seconds what we extracted

Comment: Just extract those parts and add it all together.