# Oracle 11g SQL - group by timestamp

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, group-by

in a Cx_Oracle 11g Database I have two columns: 'timestamp' and 'value'. I need a query to get the value average every one hour time. Which is the best way to do this? Timestamp is in seconds starting from epoch.

Comment: Do you need to handle leap seconds?

Comment: @MT0 No, I don't need to.

Comment: @MT0 Why the minus 1 on the question?

Comment: Not my down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `TIMESTAMP` column is of the `TIMESTAMP` data type then truncate the `TIMESTAMP` value to the hour and then group by that:

```
SELECT   TRUNC( timestamp_column, 'HH24' ) AS timestamp_hours,
         AVG( value ) AS average_value
FROM     your_table
GROUP BY TRUNC( timestamp_column, 'HH24' );
```

If:

> Timestamp is in seconds starting from epoch.

```
SELECT   TRUNC( epoch_column / 3600 ) AS hours_from_epoch,
         AVG( value ) AS average_value
FROM     your_table
GROUP BY TRUNC( epoch_column / 3600 );
```

If you need to [handle leap seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31136211/1509264) then you will need a list of leap seconds (and to maintain it in the future) and then take this into account when working out the hours.

Comment: I'm not the owner, how can I check the column data type?

Comment: I've found it using `select data_type` and i see that `TIMESTAMP` is a NUMBER data_type.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! I suppose i just need to use different function when i need different aggregation(e.g. max, min) in the same slice of time.