# How to convert timestamp with milliseconds to date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have *MSSTAMP* as "timestamp with milliseconds" in Oracle, format: 1483228800000. How can I cast that milliseconds timestamp into a date format "YYYY-MM", in order to get count of FINISHED rows per month for previous years.

I have tried different variations of TO_DATE, CAST, TO_CHAR - but I'm unable to get this working.

```
select 
  count(*) "EVENTS",
  TO_DATE(MSSTAMP, 'YYYY-MM') "FINISHED_MONTH"
from 
  DB_TABLE
where 
  MSSTAMP < '1483228800000' 
and 
  STATUS in ('FINISHED') 
group by
  FINISHED_MONTH ASC
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Unix Time

If you just need to convert from milliseconds since epoch to a timestamp in the UTC timezone, then:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC'
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL( 1483228800000 / 1000, 'SECOND' )
         AS TIME
FROM   DUAL
```

Which outputs:

> | TIME |
> | --- |
> | 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 +00:00 |

It you just want the year-month then use `TRUNC( timestamp, 'MM' )` or `TO_CHAR( timestamp, 'YYYY-MM' )`.

#### Real Time (with leap seconds)

If you need to [handle leap seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31136211/1509264) then you can create a utility package that will adjust the epoch time to account for this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE time_utils
IS
  FUNCTION milliseconds_since_epoch(
    in_datetime  IN TIMESTAMP,
    in_epoch     IN TIMESTAMP DEFAULT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
  ) RETURN NUMBER;

  FUNCTION milliseconds_epoch_to_ts (
    in_milliseconds IN NUMBER,
    in_epoch        IN TIMESTAMP DEFAULT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
  ) RETURN TIMESTAMP;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY time_utils
IS
  -- List of the seconds immediately following leap seconds:
  leap_seconds CONSTANT SYS.ODCIDATELIST := SYS.ODCIDATELIST(
      DATE '1972-07-01',
      DATE '1973-01-01',
      DATE '1974-01-01',
      DATE '1975-01-01',
      DATE '1976-01-01',
      DATE '1977-01-01',
      DATE '1978-01-01',
      DATE '1979-01-01',
      DATE '1980-01-01',
      DATE '1981-07-01',
      DATE '1982-07-01',
      DATE '1983-07-01',
      DATE '1985-07-01',
      DATE '1988-01-01',
      DATE '1990-01-01',
      DATE '1991-01-01',
      DATE '1992-07-01',
      DATE '1993-07-01',
      DATE '1994-07-01',
      DATE '1996-01-01',
      DATE '1997-07-01',
      DATE '1999-01-01',
      DATE '2006-01-01',
      DATE '2009-01-01',
      DATE '2012-07-01',
      DATE '2015-07-01',
      DATE '2016-01-01'
    );

  HOURS_PER_DAY           CONSTANT BINARY_INTEGER := 24;
  MINUTES_PER_HOUR        CONSTANT BINARY_INTEGER := 60;
  SECONDS_PER_MINUTE      CONSTANT BINARY_INTEGER := 60;
  MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND CONSTANT BINARY_INTEGER := 1000;

  MINUTES_PER_DAY         CONSTANT BINARY_INTEGER := HOURS_PER_DAY   * MINUTES_PER_HOUR;
  SECONDS_PER_DAY         CONSTANT BINARY_INTEGER := MINUTES_PER_DAY * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;

  MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE CONSTANT BINARY_INTEGER := SECONDS_PER_MINUTE * MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
  MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR   CONSTANT BINARY_INTEGER := MINUTES_PER_HOUR   * MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
  MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY    CONSTANT BINARY_INTEGER := HOURS_PER_DAY      * MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR;

  FUNCTION milliseconds_since_epoch(
    in_datetime  IN TIMESTAMP,
    in_epoch     IN TIMESTAMP DEFAULT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    p_leap_milliseconds BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
    p_diff              INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(3);
  BEGIN
    IF in_datetime IS NULL OR in_epoch IS NULL THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    p_diff := in_datetime - in_epoch;

    IF in_datetime >= in_epoch THEN
      FOR i IN 1 .. leap_seconds.COUNT LOOP
        EXIT WHEN in_datetime < leap_seconds(i);
        IF in_epoch < leap_seconds(i) THEN
          p_leap_milliseconds := p_leap_milliseconds + MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    ELSE
      FOR i IN REVERSE 1 .. leap_seconds.COUNT LOOP
        EXIT WHEN in_datetime > leap_seconds(i);
        IF in_epoch > leap_seconds(i) THEN
          p_leap_milliseconds := p_leap_milliseconds - MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    END IF;

    RETURN   MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * EXTRACT( SECOND FROM p_diff )
           + MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE * EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM p_diff )
           + MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR   * EXTRACT( HOUR   FROM p_diff )
           + MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY    * EXTRACT( DAY    FROM p_diff )
           + p_leap_milliseconds;
  END milliseconds_since_epoch;

  FUNCTION milliseconds_epoch_to_ts(
    in_milliseconds IN NUMBER,
    in_epoch        IN TIMESTAMP DEFAULT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
  ) RETURN TIMESTAMP
  IS
    p_datetime TIMESTAMP;
  BEGIN
    IF in_milliseconds IS NULL OR in_epoch IS NULL THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    p_datetime := in_epoch
        + NUMTODSINTERVAL( in_milliseconds / MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND, 'SECOND' );

    IF p_datetime >= in_epoch THEN
      FOR i IN 1 .. leap_seconds.COUNT LOOP
        EXIT WHEN p_datetime < leap_seconds(i);
        IF in_epoch < leap_seconds(i) THEN
          p_datetime := p_datetime - INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    ELSE
      FOR i IN REVERSE 1 .. leap_seconds.COUNT LOOP
        EXIT WHEN p_datetime > leap_seconds(i);
        IF in_epoch > leap_seconds(i) THEN
          p_datetime := p_datetime + INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    END IF;

    RETURN p_datetime;
  END milliseconds_epoch_to_ts;
END;
/
```

Then you can do:

```sql
SELECT TIME_UTILS.milliseconds_epoch_to_ts(
         in_milliseconds => 1483228800000,
         in_epoch        => TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'
       ) AS time
FROM DUAL;
```

And get the output:

> | TIME |
> | --- |
> | 2016-12-31 23:59:33.000 |

*Note: you will need to keep the package up-to-date when new leap-seconds are proposed.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5c231b3f589e45330629e4cbcf53d079)*

#### Update:

Your query would then be:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) "EVENTS",
       TRUNC(
         TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'
           + NUMTODSINTERVAL( MSSTAMP / 1000, 'SECOND' ),
         'MM'
       ) AS FINISHED_MONTH
FROM   DB_TABLE
WHERE  MSSTAMP < 1483228800000
AND    STATUS = 'FINISHED'
GROUP BY
       TRUNC(
         TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'
           + NUMTODSINTERVAL( MSSTAMP / 1000, 'SECOND' ),
         'MM'
       );
```

Comment: This was thorough answer, but I don't understand how to implement this into my query? (Leap years, seconds, etc. are not a concern at the moment.)

Comment: I think your handling of leap-seconds it wrong, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539436/unix-time-and-leap-seconds:  *The Unix time number is zero at the Unix epoch, and increases by exactly 86400 per day since the epoch.*

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am not trying to handle Unix time in the leap-second implementation (and never mentioned Unix time) - I am trying to handle real time when there are not always 86400 seconds per day. If you want to handle Unix time then just use the top method (which uses Oracle's `TIMESTAMP` and `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` implementations which always has 60 seconds per minute).

Comment: Well, yes Unix time is even not mentioned in question - although very likely based on given numbers.