# Converting data having unix timestamps randomly in data of one column of Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, informatica-powercenter

Eg: One row in one column contains below data.I need to convert the unix timestamps to actual datetime in oracle.Please provide sql query to convert.
NOTE: {EOT} is special character End of Transmission.
{ETX} is special character End of Text.

```
1550226213{EOT}Bharath
testtest{ETX}1550226559{EOT}LakshmanUpdate to Current Summary: {EOT}Under Investigation{EOT}
suresh{ETX}1550227918S{EOT}itaUpdate to Current Summary: {EOT}Outage restored- Under Observation
{ETX}1550301176{EOT}Rama
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the times are all at the start of each line within the string then you can use a recursive subquery-factoring clause to iterate over each sub-string line within the string and regular expressions to find each time at the start of that line and then all you need to do is [add the offset interval to the epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43066880/1509264) the time is being measured from (i.e. 1970-01-01):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, value ) AS
SELECT 1, '1550226213Bharath
1550226559LakshmanUpdate to Current Summary: Under Investigation
1550227918SitaUpdate to Current Summary: Outage restored- Under Observation
1550301176Rama' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '0ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '1234567890A
1234567891B
1234567892C' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
WITH lines ( id, value, unix_time, description, line_no, total_lines ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^\d+', 1, 1, 'm' ) ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^\d+(.*)$', 1, 1, 'm', 1 ),
         1,
         COALESCE( REGEXP_COUNT( value, '^\d+', 1, 'm' ), 0 )
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^\d+', 1, line_no + 1, 'm' ) ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^\d+(.*)$', 1, line_no + 1, 'm', 1 ),
         line_no + 1,
         total_lines
  FROM   lines
  WHERE  line_no < total_lines
)
SELECT id,
       DATE '1970-01-01' + unix_time * INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS time,
       description
FROM   lines
ORDER BY id, line_no;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | TIME                | DESCRIPTION                                                      
> -: | :------------------ | :----------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | 2019-02-15 10:23:33 | Bharath                                                          
>  1 | 2019-02-15 10:29:19 | LakshmanUpdate to Current Summary: Under Investigation           
>  1 | 2019-02-15 10:51:58 | SitaUpdate to Current Summary: Outage restored- Under Observation
>  1 | 2019-02-16 07:12:56 | Rama                                                             
>  2 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | ABC                                                              
>  3 | null                | null                                                             
>  4 | 2009-02-13 23:31:30 | A                                                                
>  4 | 2009-02-13 23:31:31 | B                                                                
>  4 | 2009-02-13 23:31:32 | C
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c9e3e963c3754d743b90d4c44fe48d5e)*

---

**Update**:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, value ) AS
SELECT 1, '1550226213{EOT}Bharath
testtest{ETX}1550226559{EOT}LakshmanUpdate to Current Summary: {EOT}Under Investigation{EOT}
suresh{ETX}1550227918{EOT}itaUpdate to Current Summary: {EOT}Outage restored- Under Observation
{ETX}1550301176{EOT}Rama' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '0{EOT}ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '1234567890{EOT}A{ETX}1234567891{EOT}B{ETX}1234567892{EOT}C' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
WITH lines ( id, value, line, line_no, total_lines ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '(.+?)(\{ETX\}|$)', 1, 1, 'n', 1 ),
         1,
         COALESCE( REGEXP_COUNT( value, '(.+?)(\{ETX\}|$)', 1, 'n' ), 0 )
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '(.+?)(\{ETX\}|$)', 1, line_no + 1, 'n', 1 ),
         line_no + 1,
         total_lines
  FROM   lines
  WHERE  line_no < total_lines
)
SELECT id,
       DATE '1970-01-01' + TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( line, '^(\d+)(\{EOT\}|$)', 1, 1, 'n', 1 ) ) * INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS time,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( line, '^(\d+)\{EOT\}(.*)$', 1, 1, 'n', 2 ) AS description
FROM   lines
ORDER BY id, line_no;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | TIME                | DESCRIPTION                                                               
> -: | :------------------ | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | 2019-02-15 10:23:33 | Bharath<br>testtest                                                       
>  1 | 2019-02-15 10:29:19 | LakshmanUpdate to Current Summary: {EOT}Under Investigation{EOT}<br>suresh
>  1 | 2019-02-15 10:51:58 | itaUpdate to Current Summary: {EOT}Outage restored- Under Observation<br> 
>  1 | 2019-02-16 07:12:56 | Rama                                                                      
>  2 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | ABC                                                                       
>  3 | null                | null                                                                      
>  4 | 2009-02-13 23:31:30 | A                                                                         
>  4 | 2009-02-13 23:31:31 | B                                                                         
>  4 | 2009-02-13 23:31:32 | C
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9c59e0e5e890682eedf831c36448590d)*

Comment: @MTO, The data i provided is in single cell in oracle table. The unix timestamps may appear at any position with EOT after that unix timestamp. I want to replace those unix timestamps with datetime whenever i find it in data.

Comment: @Rajesh My test data has your string as a single column/row value and dynamically splits it up into one row per-line. What is "EOT"? I have assumed that your timestamps will appear at the start of the string or after a line-feed character as that appears to be what your test-data shows. If the output is not to your liking then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59371691/edit) your question to give details of your expectations; you have not told us exactly what you want so we're guessing so don't blame us if we don't meet expectations we've not been told about.

Comment: @MTO. Sorry for my incomplete question.Edited the Question. Please help us.

Comment: @Rajesh Updated to use `{EOT}`/`{ETX}` separators.