# Oracle - Convert Unixtime to local datetime including DST (Daylight Savings Time) and vice versa

Tags: sql, oracle, unix-timestamp

I have a `NUMBER field` (UTCSTAMP) with UnixTimestamps and I would like to have a (custom) function to easily return local datetime (Europe/Amsterdam) including DST (Daylight Savings Time).
The output should be this format: `'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'`
For example: `unix_ts2date_function(1576666800)`

I found this article: [Convert Unixtime to Datetime SQL (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554405/convert-unixtime-to-datetime-sql-oracle/10554521#10554521) but it **doesn't** take Daylight Savings Time into account.

I would also like to have a (custom) function to easily convert a local datetime (Europe/Amsterdam) including DST (Daylight Savings Time) to a UnixTimestamp and use it in a WHERE clause.
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE UTCSTAMP > date2unix_ts_function('2019-05-01') (DST is active)
AND UTCSTAMP < date2unix_ts_function('2020-11-30') (DST not active)
```

I also found this article: [Convert timestamp datatype into unix timestamp Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105691/convert-timestamp-datatype-into-unix-timestamp-oracle) but it also doesn't take Daylight Savings Time into account.

Comment: Mostly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066665/how-to-convert-timestamp-with-milliseconds-to-date-in-oracle/43066880#43066880 but just with added time-zone conversion afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `utcstamp` seconds to the epoch `1970-01-01 UTC` (as a `TIMESTAMP` data type) and then use `AT TIME ZONE` to convert it to your desired time zone:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( utcstamp ) AS
SELECT 1576666800 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT ( TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + utcstamp * INTERVAL '1' SECOND )
         AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Amsterdam' AS Amsterdam_Time
FROM   your_table
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | AMSTERDAM_TIME                                 |
> | :--------------------------------------------- |
> | 2019-12-18 12:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/AMSTERDAM |
> ```

**Query 2**:

If you want it as a `DATE` then just wrap everything in a `CAST`:

```sql
SELECT CAST(
         ( TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + utcstamp * INTERVAL '1' SECOND )
           AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Amsterdam'
         AS DATE
       ) AS Amsterdam_Time
FROM   your_table
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | AMSTERDAM_TIME      |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2019-12-18 12:00:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=79af08c15d8c31c340455bde4d30ad42)*

---

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION DATE_TO_UTCEPOCHTIME (
  dt IN DATE,
  tz IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'UTC'
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN ROUND(
           ( CAST( FROM_TZ( dt, tz ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE )
             - DATE '1970-01-01' )
           * 24 * 60 * 60
         );
END;
/

CREATE FUNCTION UTCEPOCHTIME_TO_DATE(
  utctime IN NUMBER,
  tz      IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'UTC'
) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN ( TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + utctime * INTERVAL '1' SECOND )
           AT TIME ZONE tz;
END;
/
```

then you can do:

```sql
SELECT utcepochtime_to_date( utcstamp, 'Europe/Amsterdam' )
FROM   your_table;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | UTCEPOCHTIME_TO_DATE(UTCSTAMP,'EUROPE/AMSTERDAM') |
> | :------------------------------------------------ |
> | 2019-12-18 12:00:00                               |
> ```

and

```sql
SELECT date_to_utcepochtime(
         DATE '2019-12-18' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,
         'Europe/Amsterdam'
       ) AS utcepochtime
FROM   DUAL;
```

which outputs:

> ```
> | UTCEPOCHTIME |
> | -----------: |
> |   1576666800 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f26a179306ed4ffc4fe13fed593ddc5f)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm asking for two functions: `unix_ts2date_function()` and `date2unix_ts_function()`. How would you wrap your code into these functions?

Comment: So they can be used in the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clause

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to use the function: `date_to_utcepochtime` like:
`date_to_utcepochtime('2019-12-18 16:15:00')`
having the default timezone set to `'Europe/Amsterdam'`. So without:
`DATE '2019-12-18' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,         'Europe/Amsterdam'`.
Is that possible?

Comment: Set the default value to `'Europe/Amsterdam'` rather than `'UTC'` and don't pass dates as strings; use the correct data type, a date. You can use `DATE '2019-12-18' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND` or `TO_DATE( '2019-12-18 16:15:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )` or even `TIMESTAMP '2019-12-18 16:15:00'`. If you really must pass a string (don't) then just use `TO_DATE` in the function.

Comment: Thank you MT0. I've managed to create both functions with your support. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using the following query where we have used `FROM_TZ` to convert UTC to `Europe/Amsterdam` time:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ( CAST( DATE '1970-01-01' + 1576666800/(24*60*60) AS TIMESTAMP ), 'UTC' )
  3             AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Amsterdam', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as "desired_date"
  4  FROM
  5      DUAL;

desired_date
-------------------
2019-12-18 12:00:00

SQL>
```

Daylight saving is automatically handled when we use the long name of the timezone which is `'Europe/Amsterdam'` in our case.

Cheers!!