# Make datetime in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I make a datetime from an existing datetime. Say I have got a datetime from a table, I want to add 5 days into the date and manually enter the time.

Adding days can be achieved with +, but what about editing date and time at the same time?

```
INSERT INTO myTable (my_no, my_datetime)
SELECT a_no
       a_datetime + 5
FROM a;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ***Oracle SQL***, you can achieve the same result by using the `DATE` and `INTERVAL` syntax. Here's how you can create a new datetime by adding 5 days to an existing datetime and also manually setting the time:

```sql
INSERT INTO myTable (my_no, my_datetime)
SELECT a_no, a_datetime + INTERVAL '5' DAY + INTERVAL '3' HOUR + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
FROM a;
```

In this Oracle SQL query:

`INTERVAL '5' DAY` adds 5 days to the a_datetime value.
`INTERVAL '3' HOUR` adds 3 hours to the result of step 1, setting the time to 3:00 AM.
`INTERVAL '30' MINUTE` adds 30 minutes to the result of step 2, setting the time to 3:30 AM.
You can adjust the values in the `INTERVAL` expressions to set the specific time you want for the `my_datetime` column.

Comment: Or, more concisely, `a_datetime + INTERVAL '5 03:30' DAY TO MINUTE`.

Answer (score 0):

We tend to do it as simple as possible, and that's what @todevv presented. Another option, which isn't that obvious (but was used *before* intervals were introduced), is to actually *calculate* number of hours/minutes/seconds as parts of a day because - in Oracle date arithmetic - we add (or subtract) number of **days** to/from `date` datatype value.

Here's an example.

First, I'll set date format, just to know *what is what* (you don't have to do that):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table test as select trunc(sysdate) datum from dual;

Table created.

SQL> select * from test;

DATUM
-------------------
03.10.2023 00:00:00
```

The *oldfashioned* way of doing it:

```
SQL> update test set
  2    datum = datum
  3          + 5              -- days
  4          + 14/24          -- hours (as there are 24 hours in a day)
  5          + 30/(24*60)     -- minutes (as there are 24*60=1440 minutes in a day)
  6          + 18/(24*60*60)  -- seconds (as there are 24*60*60=86400 seconds in a day)
  7  /

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from test;

DATUM
-------------------
08.10.2023 14:30:18
```

Just to illustrate that intervals make the same result, but much more obviously:

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> update test set
  2    datum = datum
  3          + interval '5' day
  4          + interval '14' hour
  5          + interval '30' minute
  6          + interval '18' second
  7  /

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from test;

DATUM
-------------------
08.10.2023 14:30:18

SQL>
```

Comment: Beware that manual calculations will always fail to comply with calendar irregularities: leap years and seconds, daylight saving time, months with different lengths... This is an interesting piece of knowledge but probably not something you should be doing.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Manipulating a `DATE` data type by adding an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` (or a decimal number of days) will always take into account leap years and months of different lengths. If you are worried about DST then you should not be using a `DATE` data-type but `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and Oracle (and most other languages) [does not support leap-seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31136211/1509264) so if that is necessary then you will need to manually support it.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I was referring to manual calculations, not interval based ones. And I'm not saying that every single use case is doomed, just that it's easy to make mistakes: https://dbfiddle.uk/8fhq5l_E

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Your example is tangential to the question because you are adding years and not days. In that case, you should use neither of your examples and should use the `ADD_MONTHS` function (which will work for leap years when `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` data types will not) [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pY4_TGL4)