# TIMESTAMPDIFF in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, timestamp

I've seen documentation for a TIMESTAMPDIFF function in Oracle [here](https://docs.oracle.com/html/A95915_01/sqfunc.htm#i1006893), but it mentions it's for "Oracle9i Lite".

When I try to use the example on Oracle 11g:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_DAY, CURRENT_DATE, '1998-12-09') FROM DUAL;
```

I get an invalid identifier error on TIMESTAMPDIFF.  Is this feature not available in Oracle 11g?  Or is it something my DBA needs to configure?

Comment: Do you have a column called CURRENT_DATE or did you mean to use SYSDATE?

Comment: @Mihai: `CURRENT_DATE` is valid in 11g. It's similar to `SYSDATE`, but is sensitive to the session timezone.

Comment: Learning something new everyday @Allan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That function doesn't exist in Oracle RDMBS; it clearly did in Oracle Lite (which I've never encountered) and I believe it's in other databases like MySQL.

There is documentation covering [datetime and interval arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG250) which will get you part of the way there; you can either subtract one timestamp from another; or one date from another, or a mix of the two - but it's simpler to stick to one data type. Depending which you use you'll either get an interval or a number representing the number of days:

```
SQL> SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP '1998-12-09 00:00:00' FROM DUAL;

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-TIMESTAMP'1998-12-0900:00:00'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+000006169 16:16:21.287166000

SQL> SELECT CURRENT_DATE - DATE '1998-12-09' FROM DUAL;

CURRENT_DATE-DATE'1998-12-09'
-----------------------------
                   6169.67775
```

If you just want the number of whole days you can use [`extract()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions059.htm) for the interval to get just the element you want, or [`trunc()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions221.htm) for the number to remove the fractional part:

```
SQL> SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP '1998-12-09 00:00:00') FROM DUAL;

EXTRACT(DAYFROMCURRENT_TIMESTAMP-TIMESTAMP'1998-12-0900:00:00')
---------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           6169

SQL> SELECT TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE - DATE '1998-12-09') FROM DUAL;

TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE-DATE'1998-12-09')
------------------------------------
                                6169
```

You could also [`trunc()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm) the current date before comparison if you prefer, so you're comparing both at midnight, which means there won't be a fractional day part to remove:

```
SQL> SELECT TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) - DATE '1998-12-09' FROM DUAL;

TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)-DATE'1998-12-09'
------------------------------------
                                6169
```

I've used ANSI date literals for the fixed date, but you can use an existing date or timestamp variable or column; or `to_date()` or `to_timestamp()` if you have a string in a different format.

---

You can also use `extract()` to convert an interval's components to a combined value, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22608475/266304); and also make sure you're aware of the difference between [`current_date` and `sysdate`, and the timestamp equivalents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17922106/266304).

Answer (score 1):

I've never encountered TIMESTAMPDIFF, but you can accomplish something similar by simply applying regular math to your date values:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - to_timestamp('1998-12-09','yyyy-mm-dd') FROM DUAL;
```