# SQL Extract Values from Timestamp Difference

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, datediff

I'm trying to extract Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds from the output of subtracting two timestamps in an Oracle database. I then want to take the extracted values and put them into separate columns. I am able to accomplish this using substr but that doesn't seem efficient. Is there a more efficient and programmatic way of extracting the values?  Below is an example query with the current and desired output.

**Example:**

```
SELECT 

to_timestamp('2019-11-10 15:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') -
to_timestamp('2019-10-25 13:25:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')  
as TIME_DIFF,

SUBSTR(to_timestamp('2019-11-10 15:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') -
to_timestamp('2019-10-25 13:25:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), 9, 2)  
as DAYS

from dual
```

**Current Output:**

```
TIME_DIFF                     | DAYS
------------------------------+-----
+000000016 01:35:00.000000000 | 16
```

**Desired Output:**

```
DAYS | HOUR | MIN | SS
-----+------+-----+---+
16   |  01  |  35 | 00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `extract()` to pull out the required values from the interval:

```
with t as (
    select to_timestamp('2019-11-10 15:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') -
        to_timestamp('2019-10-25 13:25:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')  
        as TIME_DIFF
    from dual
)
select 
    extract(day from time_diff) days,
    extract(hour from time_diff) hours,
    extract(minute from time_diff) minutes,
    extract(second from time_diff) seconds
from t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=11c355d0687c4af6653fb490dbbc148a)**:

```
DAYS | HOURS | MINUTES | SECONDS
---: | ----: | ------: | ------:
  16 |     1 |      35 |       0
```

Comment: thanks! This is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome @MBasith! Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at `extract()`  Checkout this answer: [TIMESTAMPDIFF in Oracle 11g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440030/timestampdiff-in-oracle-11g#answer-33440498)