# Predefined functions for extracting "work hours" from two timestamps in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have two timestamps and I must find the "working hours" in between these two timestamps where "working hours" is defined as 9:00 to 17:00 (9AM to 5PM).

Given the timestamps `2022-04-25 15:00:00` and `2022-04-27 10:00:00`:

`2022-04-25 15:00:00` -> 2 hours

`2022-04-26` -> 8 hours (full day)

`2022-04-27 10:00:00` -> 1 hour

So the total would be 11 working hours.

I know how to do this in SQL with the `EXTRACT` function but I'm not as adept in JavaScript and my search hasn't returned anything useful.  Alternatively, I could add up the time that falls in the "work hours" given two timestamps but I want to check if there's some pre-defined function for this.

SQL equivalent: [SQL extract hour from timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43226380/8278075)

Comment: `new Date(timestampString).getHours()` will do the same as the SQL `EXTRACT( HOUR FROM timestampString::TIMESTAMP)` , but that doesn't really solve your problem with the working hours overlap?

Answer (score 0):

#### Native API?

There is no easy API for this in JavaScript. You have to write such functionality yourself.

#### Possible solution

Here one approach to do that:

```js
/**
 * Calculate working hours in a given time range. Does not take weekends into account.
 * @param {Date} start start Date of range
 * @param {Date} end end Date of range
 * @param {number} whStart start of working hours
 * @param {number} whEnd end of working hours
 * @returns object containing total working hours in range and working hours per day in milliseconds (ms) and hours (h)
 */
function workingHoursInRange(start, end, whStart, whEnd) {
  let totalTime = 0;
  // get day difference between start and end date
  const dayDiff = end.getDate() - start.getDate() + 1;
  let diff = 0;
  const workingHoursPerDay = [...Array(dayDiff)].map((_, i) => {
    // first day (start time till end of working hours)
    if (i === 0) diff = firstDay(start, whStart, whEnd);
    // last day (start of working hours till end date)
    else if (i === dayDiff - 1) diff = lastDay(end, whStart, whEnd);
    // days inbetween are full days
    else diff = (whEnd - whStart) * 1000 * 3600;
    totalTime += diff;
    return diff;
  });
  return {
    workingHoursPerDay: {
      ms: workingHoursPerDay,
      h: workingHoursPerDay.map((it) => it / (1000 * 3600)),
    },
    totalHours: {
      ms: totalTime,
      h: totalTime / (1000 * 3600),
    },
  };
}

/**
 * Calculate working hours on first day of a date range
 * @param {Date} date date
 * @param {number} whStart start of working hours
 * @param {number} whEnd end of working hours
 * @returns working hours in milliseconds
 */
function firstDay(date, whStart, whEnd) {
  const minEnd = new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth(),
    date.getDate(),
    whEnd
  );
  const maxStart = new Date(
    Math.max(
      new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), whStart),
      date
    )
  );
  return minEnd - maxStart;
}

/**
 * Calculate working hours on last day of a date range
 * @param {Date} date date
 * @param {number} whStart start of working hours
 * @param {number} whEnd end of working hours
 * @returns working hours in milliseconds
 */
function lastDay(date, whStart, whEnd) {
  const maxStart = new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth(),
    date.getDate(),
    whStart
  );
  const minEnd = new Date(
    Math.min(
      new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), whEnd),
      date
    )
  );
  return minEnd - maxStart;
}

// Test
const workingHoursStart = 9;
const workingHoursEnd = 17;
const input = [
  {
    start: new Date("2022-04-25 01:00:00"),
    end: new Date("2022-04-27 10:00:00"),
  },
  {
    start: new Date("2022-04-25 12:00:00"),
    end: new Date("2022-04-27 10:00:00"),
  },
  {
    start: new Date("2022-04-26 12:33:00"),
    end: new Date("2022-04-26 16:05:00"),
  },
];
// calculate working hours for all ranges
const result = input.map(({ start, end }) =>
  workingHoursInRange(start, end, workingHoursStart, workingHoursEnd)
);
// log result
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

> Please note: currently this implementation does not take into account weekends but with some small adjustments this could be considered as well.

Essentially the idea is to split a date range into three parts:

- first day
- last day
- days inbetween

The working hours on the first day will be determines by the maximum of the `working hours start` and the actual `start date`. For the last day the minimum of `working hours end` and `end date` will determine the total working hours on that day. For all days inbetween are full work days and we can just use the difference between `working hours end` and `working hours start` to calculate the total working hours.

This approach avoids possible caveats with date arithmetic such as daylight saving.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know if there are any predefined functions or anything for this. You've said you've searched and didn't find a solution. So I assume there aren't any.

## A fiddle

That's why I started fiddling! I liked the challenge. ;-) The code below does basically do what you want in the example I guess. It's more a proof of concept.

But that's also why there are still a few things that you need cover from here an out in a real use-case:

- I didn't account for minutes for example
- I didn't account for weekends
- I didn't account for two timestamps that are between different months 
  (from april 25 to may 2 for example)
- Breaks?

But that's just some fine-tuning!!

```js
function calcWorkedHours(start, end) {
  let workedHours = 0;
  let startDateTime = new Date(start);
  let endDateTime = new Date(end);
  let workDate = startDateTime.getDate();

  while (workDate <= endDateTime.getDate()) {
    if (workDate === startDateTime.getDate()) {
      // if they started before 17 oclock.
      if (startDateTime.getHours() < 17) {
        let workedHoursStartDate = 17 - startDateTime.getHours();
        console.log(workedHoursStartDate);
        workedHours += workedHoursStartDate;
      }
    } 
    else if (workDate === endDateTime.getDate()) {
      // if they finished after 9 oclock.
      if (startDateTime.getHours() > 9) {
        let workedHoursEndDate = endDateTime.getHours() - 9;
        console.log(workedHoursEndDate);
        workedHours += workedHoursEndDate;
      }
    } 
    else {
      let workedHoursFullDay = 8;
      console.log(workedHoursFullDay);
      workedHours += workedHoursFullDay;
    }

    workDate++;
  }

  console.log("Worked hours: " + workedHours);
  return workedHours;
}


calcWorkedHours("2022-04-25 15:00:00", "2022-04-27 10:00:00");
```