# Convert local datetime (with time zone) to a Unix timestamp in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I currently have a SQL query that returns the correct local `DATETIME` from a Unix `TIMESTAMP` column in our DB.

Here is an example using a specific `TIMESTAMP` of `1539961967000`:

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + 1539961967000 * (1/24/60/60/1000) AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'America/Denver' DATETIME
FROM dual;
```

which returns:

```
DATETIME
19-OCT-18 09.12.47.000000000 AM AMERICA/DENVER
```

I am having a hard time reversing this query to return a Unix `TIMESTAMP` starting with a local `DATETIME`.

Has anyone ever encountered this before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert timestamp datatype into unix timestamp Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105691/convert-timestamp-datatype-into-unix-timestamp-oracle)

Comment: Can your Unix timestamp have fractions of a second? If it can, then your **direct** process, of converting it to an Oracle timestamp, is already incorrect. That is because the `date` data type in Oracle (and that is what you get when you add a "number of days" to a `date` literal) discards fractions of a second (like milliseconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that Oracle has two ways (at least) to convert a number of seconds to an interval day-to-second - either with a function or with a simple arithmetic operation on an interval literal - but no direct way to do the reverse.

In the two queries below, first I show how to convert a UNIX timestamp (in milliseconds since the Epoch) to an Oracle timestamp, without losing milliseconds. (See my comment under your Question, where I point out that your method will lose milliseconds.) Then I show how to reverse the process.

Like you, I ignore the difference between "timestamp at UTC" and "Unix timestamp" caused by "Unix timestamp" ignoring leap seconds. Your business must determine whether that is important.

**Unix timestamp to Oracle timestamp with time zone (preserving milliseconds)**:

```
with
  inputs (unix_timestamp) as (
    select 1539961967186 from dual
  )
select from_tz(timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' 
               + interval '1' second * (unix_timestamp/1000), 'UTC')
                   at time zone 'America/Denver' as oracle_ts_with_timezone
from   inputs
;

ORACLE_TS_WITH_TIMEZONE               
--------------------------------------
2018-10-19 09:12:47.186 America/Denver
```

**Oracle timestamp with time zone to Unix timestamp (preserving milliseconds)**:

```
with
  sample_data (oracle_ts_with_timezone) as (
    select to_timestamp_tz('2018-10-19 09:12:47.186 America/Denver', 
                           'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff tzr')           from dual
  )
select ( extract(second from ts) 
         + (trunc(ts, 'mi') - date '1970-01-01') * (24 * 60 * 60)
       ) * 1000 as unix_timestamp
from   ( select cast(oracle_ts_with_timezone at time zone 'UTC' 
                     as timestamp) as ts
         from   sample_data
       )
;

  UNIX_TIMESTAMP
----------------
   1539961967186
```

Comment: You are correct. Our DB does support INSERTs in terms of milliseconds. We use this to record signals from equipment in our factory. Data collection could easily be set > 1 Hz by the engineering staff. I am mainly querying summary statistics for those signals, so bracketing in terms of seconds should be fine. But, I should have my queries follow the standard for the DB. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use TIMESTAMP literals also with time zone, i.e. `TIMESTAMP '2018-10-19 09:12:47.186 America/Denver'` instead of `FROM_TZ(...)` or `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(...)`

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your timestamp with timezone to UTC, and then subtract the epoch from that:

```
select timestamp '2018-10-19 09:12:47.0 AMERICA/DENVER'
  - timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 UTC' as diff
from dual;
```

which gives you an interval data type:

```
DIFF                  
----------------------
+17823 15:12:47.000000
```

You can then extract the elements from that, and multiply each element by an appropriate factor to convert it to milliseconds (i.e. for days, 60*60*24*1000); and then add them together:

```
select extract(day from diff) * 86400000
  + extract(hour from diff) * 3600000
  + extract(minute from diff) * 60000
  + extract(second from diff) * 1000 as unixtime
from (
  select timestamp '2018-10-19 09:12:47.0 AMERICA/DENVER'
    - timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 UTC' as diff
  from dual
);

            UNIXTIME
--------------------
       1539961967000
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ea0c8afa19ddfccfe82c6f584aa0e7a3)

This preserves milliseconds too, if the starting timestamp has them (this converts from a 'Unix' time while preserving them):

```
select (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 UTC' + (1539961967567 * interval '0.001' second))
  at time zone 'America/Denver' as denver_time
from dual;

DENVER_TIME                                 
--------------------------------------------
2018-10-19 09:12:47.567000000 AMERICA/DENVER
```

then to convert back:

```
select extract(day from diff) * 86400000
  + extract(hour from diff) * 3600000
  + extract(minute from diff) * 60000
  + extract(second from diff) * 1000 as unixtime
from (
  select timestamp '2018-10-19 09:12:47.567 AMERICA/DENVER'
    - timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 UTC' as diff
  from dual
);

            UNIXTIME
--------------------
       1539961967567
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1cdd31b95fb9a35beacee58a58113303)

If your starting timestamp has greater precision than that then you'll need to truncate (or round/floor/ceil/cast) to avoid having a non-integer result; this version just truncates the extracted milliseconds part:

```
select diff,
  extract(day from diff) * 86400000
  + extract(hour from diff) * 3600000
  + extract(minute from diff) * 60000
  + trunc(extract(second from diff) * 1000) as unixtime
from (
  select timestamp '2018-10-19 09:12:47.123456789 AMERICA/DENVER'
    - timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 UTC' as diff
  from dual
);

DIFF                                  UNIXTIME
------------------------- --------------------
+17823 15:12:47.123456789        1539961967123
```

Without that truncation (or equivalent) you'd end up with `1539961967123.456789`.

---

I'd forgotten about the leap seconds discrepancy; if you need/want to handle that, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42925181/266304).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think that mathguy‘s response is more appropriate since I should account for milliseconds. Thanks for your contribution, I appreciate it.

Comment: @ncFoCo - you may prefer my answer for other reasons, but in terms of converting **back** from Oracle timestamp with time zone to Unix timestamp, Alex's answer preserves milliseconds too.

Comment: `... AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` is not required. Oracle performs all timestamp arithmetic in UTC time, see [Datetime and Interval Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG250)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - yes, brain fade.. no idea why I included that. Thanks.